# how to use `extractValue` in oracle for XML Types with namespaces

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle, xmltype

how to use `extractValue` in oracle for XML Types with namespaces?

```
<tns:hdr xmlns:tns="MY-NS-HERE">
    <feed_freq_typ>M</feed_freq_typ>
    <myTag>
        <myId>001308</myId>
    </myTag>
</tns:hdr>
```

I have tried using the following query:

```
select * from xml_table where extractValue(xml_val,'hdr/myTag/myId/text()') = '001308';
```

but got 0 records.

I have also tried

```
select * from xml_table where extractValue(xml_val,'tns:hdr/myTag/myId/text()') = '001308';
```

and got an error as below.

[image: Oracle Error]

Please help me get this query right.

**EDIT**

This question is certainly not a duplicate of the question of which it is marked as duplicate. It is similar but not duplicate. The other question is about some other function.

Comment: [`EXTRACTVALUE( xmltype_instance, xpath_string, namespace_string )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions052.htm) - just specify the third argument as `'xmlns:tns="http://yourserver.url/tns/"'`

Comment: @MT0, this question is certainly different from the question that you have marked it with.

Comment: You have presented an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): "How do I solve this problem using one specific method (`EXTRACTVALUE`)?" - however, `EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are deprecated in Oracle 12c and you should be using [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) - which the linked question shows you how to get the data out with the namespaces - all your solution would need to do is add a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: But, if you absolutely must use a deprecated function, my [first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667573/how-to-use-extractvalue-in-oracle-for-xml-types-with-namespaces?noredirect=1#comment72460658_42667573) gives you the solution - just include the third argument (the namespaces string).

Comment: @MT0, All that information is relevant to my question and I thank you for that but this information is not mentioned anywhere in the question of which this question has been marked a duplicate. Hence, I again tell you that this is not a duplicate.